# Is it possible to Clone input field values in real time in a Cloned DIV? And how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a cloned div that has input fields and dropdowns. The problem is that when the information is entered the clone does not update without refreshing the browser. I would like the clone to update on keyup or down. It being a Cloned div takes away the normal solutions.

Is this even something at is possible?

**Updated** And how?

```
$(function(){
    var $dataAreaClone = $('.information_entry').clone();
    $('.read_only_data_area_C').html($dataAreaClone);
});
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a basic example in a fiddle. Typing in one master text input will update as many clones as you make of it using `keyup`:  http://jsfiddle.net/3mW8u/

Comment: Follow up question: How do I update an entire cloned div with nested selectors as the (cloned)children have the same IDs as the parent? Your script works wonderfully when copying to cloned textbox with a unique ID.

Comment: First thing is to make sure you're not cloning IDs since they're supposed to be unique. Secondly, I'm not sure I fully understand what you're doing/asking. If you clone <div id="master"><input type="text" class="text1"/><input type="text" class="text2"/></div>, you can still automagically update all of the input.text1 fields separately from the input.text2 fields.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

Yeah I know I could have put it in a comment but it fully answers the question. :))

**Edit:** You can add a listener, and just copy the value on the new divs.

To add listener you can do something like:

```
$('#mainInput').onkeyup(function(el){

     // Update values here
     $('.clonedInput').each(function(subEl){subEl.value = el.value;});

})
```

Note: For simplicity (in the example) I considered the main input has an id, and cloned inputs have same class.

Comment: :)) I'll take a look in a sec.